# xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)

Tags: xorg, radeon

I get this error in Xorg.0.log

> xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)

Googling quickly reveals that this error is caused by starting Xorg as non root user. Problem is that I'm running this as root. 
Next possible cause SELinux, that is diabled too.

Any other possible causes of this error?

My graphicscard is

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

But I have severe problems with the drivers, so I'm trying to run as Vesa, using this xorg.conf

> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "Videocard0"
>     Driver      "vesa"
>   EndSection

Comment: Did you exec anything in your .xinitrc file?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't log in as root this way, at all.  The simplest way should be to use a display manager.

Comment: What distro are you using? The default setup could have something to do with it.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/xinit
```

Fixed my problem on Linux Mint

Comment: I'm curious about the reasoning for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

Xorg is trying IO as non-root or even root on Ubuntu 22.04.

Try this as root:

```
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_RAWIO+eip /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
```

then restart Xorg