# Xorg broken xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted) No devices detected

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, nvidia, intel

I am trying to use `Xorg` instead of `Wayland` on my Arch Linux.

I have two graphics cards in my laptop. An Intel and a Nvidia graphics card.

The output of my log file is:

```
[    53.401] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[    53.403] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.0
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    53.403] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[    53.403] Current Operating System: Linux thinkpad 4.17.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 18 09:56:24 UTC 2018 x86_64
[    53.403] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=4c4cf377-77af-4cd1-bd40-6d94fae4e2f1 rw quiet resume=UUID=4a1be855-ae3e-4add-b3e0-3b3abb817115 nvidia-drm.modeset=1
[    53.403] Build Date: 18 June 2018  03:12:37PM
[    53.403]  
[    53.403] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    53.404]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    53.404] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    53.404] (==) Log file: "/home/henzler/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Fri Jul 20 17:30:51 2018
[    53.412] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    53.412] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    53.414] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    53.414] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    53.414] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    53.414] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    53.415] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    53.415] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[    53.415] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    53.415] (**) Option "DontZap" "false"
[    53.415] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    53.415] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    53.415] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    53.415] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    53.415] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    53.415] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[    53.415]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    53.415] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    53.415]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    53.415] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[    53.415] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg"
[    53.415] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    53.415] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    53.415]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    53.415]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[    53.415]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    53.415]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    53.416] (++) using VT number 3

[    53.420] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c3
[    53.422] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    53.424] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[    53.424] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    53.425] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 11 paused 0
[    53.427] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg"
[    53.427] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" setting /dev/dri/card0 as PrimaryGPU
[    53.429] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:191b:17aa:5050 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf0000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000e000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    53.429] (--) PCI:*(2@0:0:0) 10de:134d:17aa:5050 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf1000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128
[    53.429] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    53.430] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    53.430] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
[    53.495] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    53.495]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    53.495]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    53.496] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  396.24  Wed Apr 25 23:17:01 PDT 2018
[    53.497] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    53.498] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    53.502] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    53.502]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 2.99.917
[    53.502]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    53.502]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    53.502] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    53.503] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    53.503] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    53.503] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    53.503] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    53.505] (II) intel(G0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20180308
[    53.505] (II) intel(G0): SNA compiled from 2.99.917-831-ge7bfc906
[    53.521] (EE) No devices detected.
[    53.521] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    53.521] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    53.521] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    53.521] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/henzler/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[    53.521] (EE) 
[    53.539] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I know there are many similar questions out there but nothing has worked for me so far.

I have done following:

- Installed `xf86-video-intel`
- Removed `xorg.conf`
- Installed CUDA + Nvidia drivers

Comment: What is your actual question? Whilst you have (helpfully) provided your objective, an error log and list of things that you have done, you haven't *explicitly* stated what the problem is. If you did so, you might get a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

What is even your objective? Do you want to use the low-power and low-performance Intel graphics, or do you want NVIDIA graphics? You installed CUDA, so I guess you plan on using your NVIDIA GPU anyway, so I'd suggest getting rid of xf86-video-intel.

Then follow the Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only

Answer (score -2):

1. ```
   [    53.503] Xorg broken xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
   ```

   In this error, if you do a search on Google about "Xorg broken xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)", you would probably stumble upon another question from Unix Stack Exchange too, such as [xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159124/xf86enableioports-failed-to-set-iopl-for-i-o-operation-not-permitted) - although it also doesn't have a confirmed answer. The answer there specifies the solution for Linux Mint only.

   If you're not running it as a root user. Then trying it out will probably solve this problem.
2. ```
   [    53.415] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
   [    53.521] (EE) No devices detected.
   ```

   These two log entries are related to each other. This states that if you encounter an error where no devices are available, then maybe try reconfiguring `udev` or disable `AutoAddDevices`.

Comment: This seems like a joke answer... in the first point your answer is to google for the solution, and in the second point you just re-iterate what the error message says.

Comment: There is already a thread about this error also in unix stackexchange and it is common for the error message to contain the solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, SE is a Q&A site, not a forum of threaded messages, so there may be a question (but not a thread) relating to this error already on SE.Unix. If so, and you know what that link is, then why not include a link to that question, in order to save the OP from having to search for it themselves (however, such a link would have probably served better as a comment). WRT to the second point, it would have served better as a comment, under the OP's question, asking them whether they have already performed the suggestions from the error message.