# Arch Linux error when running startx

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

I have an Arch Linux setup running [BSPWM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bspwm), I don't use a login manager, but instead just run `startx` (with `xinit`). When I exit BSPWM and go back to the tty, I see the following error:

```
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

I have an NVIDIA GPU (RTX 2070 Super) and have installed the (latest) proprietary drivers.

I'm not sure what is relevant to the issue, but I'll gladly include more info.

I did find [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159124/xf86enableioports-failed-to-set-iopl-for-i-o-operation-not-permitted), I didn't try the solution because frankly I'm not entirely sure what the impact of this would be (it's not really explained).

**EDIT**

I ended up trying the linked suggestion and it didn't work.

Comment: The answer suggests setting the SUID bit on the `xinit` executable. If that is the solution, then it should also work if you just run it as root. So try that first: log in as root and try `startx`. Do you get the same error? Also, are you sure it is an actual problem? Does everything work?

Comment: I did try that, however I didn't configure root to start bspwm, sorry I'm somewhat of a noob. Anyway, I did try the linked suggestion and the issue persists. I'm not sure what the original permissions of `xinit`would be, now that I see it didn't work. What `chmod` should I run to restore the original, would you happen to know that?

Comment: Just the inverse command in this case: `sudo chmod u-s /usr/bin/xinit`. Please also answer my other question: is this actually a problem? Is anything not working? Do you have any reason to think this is more than a simple debug message?

Comment: @terdon Everything seems to be working just fine, I "assumed" it's an error. I scoured the web looking for a solution. Btw, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. I am just thinking that X tends to be very verbose, so if it isn't causing you problems, I would guess you can safely ignore it.